# How did Greeks make greek fire?

Tags: war, warfare, ancient-greece, greek

How did Greeks make Greek fire? Did they put oil in the bottle because it could burn on water due to its ability of floating on it?

This is an interesting topic, although how do we put the fire out? So that's 2 questions

Comment: The composition of Greek fire is not known. Several pictures show that they did not put "oil in the bottle" but used something similar to a flame-thrower.

Answer (score 4):

We don't know how it was made because the formula for it has been lost. It was probably not even the same thing in every case, but instead a generic name for incendiary weapons. The real power of Greek Fire seems to be that the Byzantines delivered it in tube, like a flamethrower, rather than catapults.